# Java - Using an SQL database entry as a variable in a program

Tags: java, mysql, sql, variables

I can find endless tutorials on using a `Select` statement to query a database and insert new values, something common for a log-in system where you would have:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=? and password=?
```

HOWEVER

I want to do the opposite. I want to select the password, for example, from my database and use that as a String variable.

So in theory it would be:

```
String password="SELECT password FROM table WHERE username=?"
```

That is simply how I want it to work in theory, I want that password that is relative to the inputted username.

What I have at the moment

```
String pwd1 = "Select user_password FROM pif_users WHERE username=?";
        try{
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(pwd1);
            pst.setString(1,username);            
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
                System.out.println("Password is: " +pwd1);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid username/password");
            }
       }
       catch(SQLException e){

       }
```

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: Then do it, I don't see what you're asking, voted close as unclear

Comment: My theory statement wouldn't actually set the password to the variable, password though.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear, thanks.

Comment: Irony is : good picture doesn't stops SO guys from downvoting

Comment: Lol, that picture is set by gravatar, I don't use it in this to gain votes. It's universal I use that for lots of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to print the password? Then you must do:

```
System.out.println("Password is: " +rs.getString(1));
```

Or just assign the password to pwd1 like so:

```
pwd1 = rs.getString(1));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks very much! Such a simple concept yet I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it could be something like:

```
String stmt = "SELECT password FROM table WHERE username=?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(stmt);
ps.setString(1, userName);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
String password = "";
if (rs.next()) 
{
    password = rs.getString(1);
}
```

Obviously if you're statement returns other values you can change the get type and the index. If the ResultSet rs has multiple rows returned you can replace the if statement by a while statement.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I didn't try the getString method as I wasn't sure if SELECT password would set password as a string that could be accessed by java. Hence why I made this question that got downvoted so badly :(